# Babel : Error: Can't resolve 'bable-loader'

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-2, babel-loader

Having a problem with babel-loader or maybe my webpack config. If I use my current implementation works fine, but I know that the test pattern is wrong(i think). Currently a glob, not a regex. If I change it according to doc's, get the following error. I have blown away node_modules and npm installed.

> Error: Can't resolve 'bable-loader' in /path/to/app

```js
//no error
rules: [{
      test: /\*.js$/,
      use: ['ng-annotate-loader', 'bable-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },


//throws error
rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: ['ng-annotate-loader', 'bable-loader'],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },


//file : .babelrc 

{
  "env": {
    "testing": {
      "presets": [
        "es2015"
      ]
    }
  },
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", "stage-2", {
      "modules": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `babel-loader` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are misspelling `babel-loader`.. It also looks like you need a good night of sleep.

Comment: LOL! thanks a bunch, sure do! will accept as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the babel-loader plugin:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#usage

```
 module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You should be typing babel-loader. Not bable-loader. Bable is a typo, thus it cant find it.